# Why does lldb not single step?

Tags: debugging, lldb

I am struggling with `LLDB` and understanding how single step works. I have been using `si` for single step however it does not perform as expected. According to the documentation [here](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html#do-an-instruction-level-single-step-in-the-currently-selected-thread) it should single step through instructions I think.

Taking a program like this, compiling with clang (`clang test.c -o printf_test -g`) and running with lldb:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    printf("Hello \n");
    printf("world\n");
    printf("!\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

I start by running process launch and then setting a breakpoint at the `main` function. Now when I run `dis` I am looking at this:

```
Process 2051 resuming
Process 2051 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'vuln-0', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x000000000040114f vuln-0`main at task_5_vuln-0.c:5:2
   2    #include <stdlib.h>
   3    
   4    int main(){
-> 5        printf("Hello ");
   6        printf("world");
   7        printf("\n");
   8        exit(0);
(lldb) dis
vuln-0`main:
    0x401140 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x401141 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x401144 <+4>:  subq   $0x10, %rsp
    0x401148 <+8>:  movl   $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
->  0x40114f <+15>: leaq   0xeae(%rip), %rdi
    0x401156 <+22>: movb   $0x0, %al
    0x401158 <+24>: callq  0x401030                  ; symbol stub for: printf
    0x40115d <+29>: leaq   0xea7(%rip), %rdi
    0x401164 <+36>: movb   $0x0, %al
    0x401166 <+38>: callq  0x401030                  ; symbol stub for: printf
    0x40116b <+43>: leaq   0xe9f(%rip), %rdi
    0x401172 <+50>: movb   $0x0, %al
    0x401174 <+52>: callq  0x401030                  ; symbol stub for: printf
    0x401179 <+57>: xorl   %edi, %edi
    0x40117b <+59>: callq  0x401040                  ; symbol stub for: exit
```

Now if I use `si` to single step to the next instruction we do not land at the next instruction `0x401156 <+22>: movb   $0x0, %al` instead we land at:

```
(lldb) si
Process 2051 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'vuln-0', stop reason = instruction step into
    frame #0: 0x00007ffff7e92eee libc.so.6`__GI___fstatat64(fd=1, file="", buf=0x00007fffffffd7e0, flag=4096) at fstatat64.c:168:3
(lldb) dis
libc.so.6`__GI___fstatat64:
    0x7ffff7e92ee0 <+0>:  endbr64 
    0x7ffff7e92ee4 <+4>:  movl   %ecx, %r10d
    0x7ffff7e92ee7 <+7>:  movl   $0x106, %eax              ; imm = 0x106 
    0x7ffff7e92eec <+12>: syscall 
->  0x7ffff7e92eee <+14>: cmpl   $0xfffff000, %eax         ; imm = 0xFFFFF000 
    0x7ffff7e92ef3 <+19>: ja     0x7ffff7e92f00            ; <+32> at fstatat64.c:167:5
    0x7ffff7e92ef5 <+21>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x7ffff7e92ef7 <+23>: retq   
    0x7ffff7e92ef8 <+24>: nopl   (%rax,%rax)
    0x7ffff7e92f00 <+32>: movq   0x104f09(%rip), %rdx
    0x7ffff7e92f07 <+39>: negl   %eax
    0x7ffff7e92f09 <+41>: movl   %eax, %fs:(%rdx)
    0x7ffff7e92f0c <+44>: movl   $0xffffffff, %eax         ; imm = 0xFFFFFFFF 
    0x7ffff7e92f11 <+49>: retq
```

If I keep executing `si` I can hit it 3 more times before the program completes and we never go back to main to hit the other `printf` methods however you can see the output from them as you keep running the `si` commands.

```
(lldb) si
Process 2692 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'vuln-0', stop reason = instruction step into
    frame #0: 0x00007ffff7dc5c87 libc.so.6`__GI___getrandom(buffer=0x00007ffff7f9f4d8, length=8, flags=1) at getrandom.c:29:10
(lldb) si
Process 2692 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'vuln-0', stop reason = instruction step into
    frame #0: 0x00007ffff7e999db libc.so.6`__brk(addr=0x0000000000000000) at brk.c:36:12
(lldb) si
Hello 
Process 2692 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'vuln-0', stop reason = instruction step into
    frame #0: 0x00007ffff7e93a37 libc.so.6`__GI___libc_write(fd=1, buf=0x00000000004052a0, nbytes=7) at write.c:26:10
(lldb) si
world
!
Process 2692 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000)
```

Using the [n](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html#do-a-source-level-single-step-over-in-the-currently-selected-thread) command will move you through source code lines as expected and the step [s](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html#do-a-source-level-single-step-in-the-currently-selected-thread) command produces the same results as `si`.

Is there a command to execute one instruction and stop? It is very hard to debug even basic programs when I move an unspecified number of instructions each time I run `si`.

OS: Linux Mint running on VirtualBox
VirtualBox: 7.0.10 r158379
Host: MacOS Ventura 13.6
LLDB Version: 17.0.2
Architecture: x86-64

Comment: That's definitely not how `si` is supposed to work.  I can't reproduce this behavior on your code built on macOS with the latest lldb from Xcode.  However, step-instruction relies on processor and OS support to set the 'single step mode', so it's both OS and architecture dependent.  So to give more help, we'd need to know your lldb version, what OS you are using and what architecture it's running on.  Probably best to file a report with this to the lldb issues tracker: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues so you get the attention of someone who supports the platform you are running on.

Comment: I have added some additional information about the environment to the question. In short I am also running macOS as my host but I am running lldb on a linux mint virtual machine. The LLDB version is 17.0.2

Comment: Please do file a bug about this if you have the chance.  The lldb testsuite does test basic stepping, and it does get run on Linux VM's successfully, so there's something wrong with the support for your configuration which we're unlikely to work out here...